# Equation involving greatest integer function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve for $x$ the following equation
>   $$\left\lfloor \frac x2 \right\rfloor\cdot \left\lfloor \frac x3 \right\rfloor\cdot\left\lfloor \frac x4 \right\rfloor=x^2.$$

I didn't have any idea for solution since I didn't encounter anything similar before.

Comment: MathJax hint:  to get floor brackets use \lfloor and \rfloor so \lfloor \frac x2 \rfloor gives $\lfloor \frac x2 \rfloor$

Comment: @RossMillikan: for the floor of a fraction, you should even wrap with \left \right. $$\left\lfloor\frac12\right\rfloor$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. A solution should be a non-negative number whose square is an integer. Clearly $x=0$ is a solution. Assume now that $x\geq 1$. By noting that, $t-1\leq \lfloor t\rfloor \leq t$, it follows
$$x^2=\lfloor x/2\rfloor \lfloor x/3\rfloor \lfloor x/4\rfloor \leq (x/2)(x/3)(x/4)\implies x\geq 24,$$ 
and 
$$x^2=\lfloor x/2\rfloor \lfloor x/3\rfloor \lfloor x/4\rfloor \geq (x/2-1)(x/3-1)(x/4-1)\implies x<33.$$
Note that in the interval $[24,33)$, we have that
$$\lfloor x/2\rfloor \lfloor x/3\rfloor \lfloor x/4\rfloor = \begin{cases}
576 & x\in [24,26) \\
624, & x\in [26,27)\\
702 & x\in [27,28)\\
882 & x\in [28,30)\\
1050 & x\in [30,32)\\
10280 & x\in [32,33)
\end{cases}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: @user373141 Consider the values of the function $\lfloor x/2\rfloor \lfloor x/3\rfloor \lfloor x/4\rfloor$ in the interval $[24,33]$. It is piecewise constant.